# Unable to mock System class static method using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, static-methods, powermock

Even though I have read the manual and gone through multiple answers for Powermock, could not mock a static method for my use case.

Class:

```
    @Component
    public class SCUtil{

        public void createSC(){
            try {
                String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
//                ...
//                ...
//                ...
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
               log.error("Exception in creasting SC");
               throw new ServiceException(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( InetAddress.class )
public class SCUtilTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SCUtil scUtil;

    private Event event;

    @Before
    public void beforeEveryTest () {
        event = new InterventionEvent();
    }
    
    @Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void testCreateSC_Exception () {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class);
        PowerMockito.when(InetAddress.getLocalHost()).thenThrow(new UnknownHostException("test"));
        scUtil.createSC(event);
    }
}
```

Here, the test is failing as no exception is being thrown:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception:
> com.example.v1.test.selftest.errorhandling.ServiceException

I have wrecked more than a couple of hours in this and still have not gotten it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for all the help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.net.InetAddress` is a system class. The caller of the system class should be defined in `@PrepareForTest({ClassThatCallsTheSystemClass.class})`.

See [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System).

> The way to go about mocking system classes are a bit different than
> usual though. Normally you would prepare the class that contains the
> static methods (let's call it X) you like to mock but because it's
> impossible for PowerMock to prepare a system class for testing so
> another approach has to be taken. So instead of preparing X you
> prepare the class that calls the static methods in X!

Please note `@InjectMocks` annotation does not inject static mocks, it can be removed.

Example of working test:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SCUtil.class)
public class SCUtilTest {

    private SCUtil scUtil = new SCUtil();

    @Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void testCreateSC_Exception () throws UnknownHostException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class);
        PowerMockito.when(InetAddress.getLocalHost()).thenThrow(new UnknownHostException("test"));
        scUtil.createSC();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the part of the doc where it specifies some differentiation for System classes.